# jQuery UI ToggleClass CSS hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, hover, toggleclass

I have a website at http://www.presentbladet.se (unfinished). When I hover the "Test product" a magnifying glass appears. So far, so good.

**Fade in - but keep hover in CSS**

I want the transition to be smooth with a fade in effect. I still want to keep as much as possible in the CSS and just make the delay / fade in jQuery / jQuery UI.

**I use this code on my site:**

```
$("li.item a").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover", 10000);
        return false;
    });
```

**Delay part don't work**

It works almost. It toggles the class "hover" but the delay part don't work at all. The transition is instant instead of fade in slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add [toggleClass part](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) of jQuery UI for `toggleClass` animation. Now your page has only the core, widgets and tab.
Go to [download page](http://jqueryui.com/download) and select `Effects Core`

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI extends the core jQuery.animate function to allow you to specify a class for the element(s) to animate to.

From the docs: "...It's heavily used by the class transition feature..."

You might want to give that a go. Something like this.

```
$("li.item a").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate("hover", 10000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
jQuery("#divId").fadeIn(500);
```

You could probably just add .fadeIn(500) to your function that's calling the image on mouseOver, I think. Adjust the number to adjust the speed or just use the words fast or slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* i Don't know exactly whether this is your requirement , if no please post a more specific code , try this code first */
    $("li.item a").hover(
    function() {$(this).addClass("hover");},
    function() {$(this).removeClass("hover");}
    );
```